# ASP.Net User Control public function is not a member

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web

I have a user control on a Web Site with this inside.

```
Namespace MenuTreePanel
Public Class MenuTreePanel
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl
    Public root As New MenuNode(0, 0, "root", "")




    Public WithEvents Spany1 As HtmlGenericControl = New HtmlGenericControl("UL")
    Public WithEvents Spany2 As HtmlGenericControl = New HtmlGenericControl("UL")
    Public WithEvents Spany3 As HtmlGenericControl = New HtmlGenericControl("UL")

    Public Function getRoot() As MenuNode
        Return root
    End Function
End Class
End Namespace
```

When I go to access the getRoot function I get Error

```
'getRoot' is not a member of 'ASP.MenuTreePanel'.
```

The namespace is incorrectly labelled as ASP, and I was wondering where that might be coming from. In the object explorer, my control is listed under both the correct namespace and the ASP namespace.

Referenced on the page using

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="MenuTreePanel" Src="~/MenuTreePanel.ascx" TagName="MenuTree" %>

<MenuTreePanel:MenuTree ID="menuTreeSelect" runat="server"></MenuTreePanel:MenuTree>
```

Edit 2:

```
    <%@ Control Language="vb" CodeBehind="~/MenuTreePanel.ascx.vb"className="MenuTreePanel" %>
```

and the attempt to access it
        Dim root As New MenuNode(0, 0, "root", "")

```
    root = (menuTreeSelect).getRoot()
```

Comment: Can you show us the control on the page?

Comment: Both the classname and namespace are the same. Maybe it's having conflicts with that. Try changing the namespace

Comment: Could you also share the header of your ascx file?

Comment: Show the code lines where you access the getRoot function

Comment: Added the requested lines. I tried changing to namespace to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't linking the CodeFile and the ASCX correctly with a Web Site.

I had to change CodeBehind to CodeFile and add an inherits, and now everything is working correctly.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely that you're attempting to access the property statically. My assumption is that you do *not* want to access it statically, since it's a control.

My suggestion is that you look at how you're using the MenuTreePanel object.

You should be accessing it like this:

```
menuTreeSelect.getRoot();
```

and **not** like this:

```
MenuTreePanel.getRoot();
```

Comment: This helped me because my usercontrol's `TagName` property and its `ID` property were the same, so the code thought I was trying to call the function statically. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Public Shared Function getRoot() As MenuNode
    Return root
End Function
```

Comment: But root isn't shared, right? Doesn't that mean this won't work?

Comment: Wasn't able to access a shared function that I just made from MenuTreePanel either.